# Aligning asp.net checkbox in section

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I've got the following markup:

```
            <section style="width:1000px;margin: 0 auto; height:20px; border:solid; border-width:2px;">
                <section style="width:300px;float:left;">
                    Routing Stage:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbStages" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDBStages" 
                        DataTextField="stages" DataValueField="StageRefID" Width="175px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </section>
                <section style="width:300px;float:left;">
                    Return Stage:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbReturnStage" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlDBStages" 
                        DataTextField="stages" DataValueField="StageRefID" Width="175px">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </section>
                <section style="width:300px;float:left; vertical-align:top;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="MatingStage"/>
                </section>
            </section>
```

for some reason the checkbox is not aligning with the rest of the controls. I've placed a border around the section to see where the section borders are but for some reason the checkbox is displayed below it.

[image: Screen Shot]

what am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following css style it will works properly,

```
#Checkbox1{
margin-top:5px;/*adjust this as per your needs*/
}
```